# Swiperjs@9.4.1 element lag when used on angular 14

Tags: angular, swiper.js

When i use Swiper Element in my angular project, I encountered lag when scrolling, hovering and modals.

Hear is my config
[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X2eH.jpg)
[Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY5zq.jpg)

In module
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
register()

Swiper directive
[Swiper directive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDgI7.jpg)

Please give me solution